# How to change the browser tab color on a PC or Mac using HTML or JS

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I understand that you can use `<meta name="theme-color" content=" #0000ffbb" />` to do it on an android phone and there is another one for the iPhone, but that is for just mobile uses. I am a little old school and prefer using my laptop for browsing the internet. I was wondering since themes can change the appearance of the browser tab how can we do that with HTML or JS? My main reason is that I am making a site and my logo is a png and if it is a dark tab the logo won't show. For example, Left side you can't even tell if I have a logo, the right side shows it.

[image]

Comment: put this as the answer so I can say it was answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, only mobile chrome and few others support this, no desktop browser except maybe Vivaldi allow this change.

Complete information on availability:

https://caniuse.com/?search=theme-color